# Installing apache modules on CentOS

Tags: apache, module, ansible, centos

I am trying to install apache modules on CentOS 8.1. I have a playbook that is working for Ubuntu and need the same tasks on CentOS.

```
  vars:
    libs:
      - apache2
      - libapache2-mod-php
      - libapache2-mod-jk
      - libapache2-mod-rpaf
      - libapache2-mod-geoip
      - php-curl
  apt:
    name: "{{ libs }}"
    state: present
    install_recommends: yes
```

I installed httpd and php on my system.

```
- name: Install apache2 on CentOS
  vars:
    libs:
      - httpd
      - httpd-devel
      - php
      - php-curl
  yum:
    name: "{{ libs }}"
    state: present
  when: ansible_distribution == "CentOS"
```

I don't know what are the mod equivalents for the ones missing. These are the apache modules I need to set.

```
- name: Set modules
  apache2_module:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - alias
    - authz_host
    - autoindex
    - deflate
    - dir
    - env
    - expires
    - headers
    - jk
    - mime
    - negotiation
    - php7.2
    - proxy 
    - proxy_http
    - rewrite
    - rpaf
    - setenvif
    - ssl
    - filter
```

Output:

```
ok: [node1] => (item=alias)
ok: [node1] => (item=authz_host)
ok: [node1] => (item=autoindex)
ok: [node1] => (item=deflate)
ok: [node1] => (item=dir)
ok: [node1] => (item=env)
ok: [node1] => (item=expires)
ok: [node1] => (item=headers)
failed: [node1] (item=jk) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "jk", "msg": "None not found. Perhaps this system does not use None to manage apache"}
ok: [node1] => (item=mime)
ok: [node1] => (item=negotiation)
failed: [node1] (item=php7.2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "php7.2", "msg": "None not found. Perhaps this system does not use None to manage apache"}
ok: [node1] => (item=proxy)
ok: [node1] => (item=proxy_http)
ok: [node1] => (item=rewrite)
failed: [node1] (item=rpaf) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "rpaf", "msg": "None not found. Perhaps this system does not use None to manage apache"}
ok: [node1] => (item=setenvif)
failed: [node1] (item=ssl) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ssl", "msg": "None not found. Perhaps this system does not use None to manage apache"}
ok: [node1] => (item=filter)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no holy grail in this process. And yes, php modules names can be differently named based on Distro's.

Based on the output, we can see that the following modules aren't found:

`ssl, rpaf, php7.2, jk`

Solution 1: Try googling for the correct names

Solution 2: Try installing the packages on the CLI yourself by using `sudo yum install libapache2-<name>*`. Note the star at the end of the command.

When you don't provide the `-y` option, yum returns the packages it wants to install, without installing them. This should give you enough hints for matching package names.

Note that you do not want to apply `ignore_errors: True` to the task, because your code might need them.

Comment: Is it normal that in my case (almalinux 8.6) there is no `libapache2-*` library ? Could not find any in the repository and I cannot seem to find information anywhere...

Comment: what do you want to install exactly and why?